# How can be computed $H_n(T_i \times T_j)$?

Tags: algebraic-topology

Here $T_g$ denotes the g-fold torus, and $T_i\times T_j$ denotes the cartesian product. My major trouble is that I can't use Kunneth's Theorem. Thanks for helping!

Comment: Maybe try induction and the long exact sequence for a pair. (There are many pairs you could choose; some slicker than others.)